# 406 Not Acceptable error when runing wget

Tags: wget, cron

I have this command in crontab:

```
wget --quiet --delete-after http://boms.ro/admincp/cron/s/9abf0f42c1e4f55fdb87d8237cdde
```

And when I run it with the --debug argument I get the following response:

```
Caching boms.ro => 188.240.2.30
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00000000010c97e0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /admincp/cron/s/9abf0f42c1e4f55fdb87d8237cdde HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: boms.ro
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---

---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 18:29:45 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 372

---response end---
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 372 bytes of body: [<html>
<head><title> 406 Not Acceptable
</title></head>
<body><h1> 406 Not Acceptable
</h1>
This request is not acceptable<hr />
Powered By <a href='http://www.litespeedtech.com'>LiteSpeed Web Server</a><br />
<font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica" size=-1>LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!</font></body></html>
] done.
```

What is considered "not acceptable" in my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing some references around that the `mod_security` (probably a bad included rule?) included with that "LiteSpeed" server package might be the cause.

Try disabling `mod_security` - and as an aside, that's a pretty weak usage of the `406` response code if that's the case.

Comment: That was the problem. I sent a ticket to the hosting provider and they  disabled it.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of 406 Not Acceptable is that your client (in this case either wget or a proxy) sent an Accept: header, but the server is unable to send the document in a format listed in the Accept: header it got.  Accept-* headers also cause the same behaviour.

Because your accept header is set to accept any MIME type and isn't including requests for specific languages or anything, this is probably a bug in the http server (or the CGI application it is running).